# set change payment method to default braintree drop-in ui

Tags: javascript, python, django, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using brain-tree as payment gateway. In that i am using drop-in UI.
in drop-in ui there is a option change payment method.
When i do the change payment method, its getting changed but its not getting to set default. And for next transaction its taking old card only not newly added card.

my js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    braintree.setup("{{ client_token }}", "dropin", {
        container: "checkout",
        form: "checkoutForm"
    });

    $("#submitPayment").on("click", function () {

        $("button").off("click");
        $("a").off("click");
        $('body').off("click");

        var btn = $(this).button("loading")
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.button('reset');
        }, 3500)
    });
});
</script>
```

form.html

```
<form id='checkoutForm' method='POST' action="/upgrade/">{% csrf_token %}

            <div id='checkout' ></div>

                <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="{{ plan }}"/>
                <input name="token" type="hidden" value="{{ client_token }}" />
                <!-- disable this when clicked -->
            <button type="button" class="btn modal-action modal-close right margin-class canceleledd"
                            style="display:none;background-color:lightcoral;color: #000000;">Cancel</button>
            <input id='submitPayment' type='submit' data-loading-text="Completing..." class='btn right margin-class' value='Pay ${{ amount }}' autocomplete="off" style="background-color:lightblue;color: #000000;"/>
</form>
```

i am not getting how to set the payment method to default when added new card.
Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

There are some things worth noting about setting the default payment method.

- The first payment method created for a customer is [set as the default](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create#new-default-payment-method)
- When you generate the client token you can pass in an option to make the [last used payment method the default payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate#options)
- The API also lets you [update a payment method and set the default](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update#options) for a customer

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

Add the `defaultFirst` option to the `braintree.setup` and your set default payment method will be automatically selected and show in the drop-in UI.

```
braintree.setup("{{ client_token }}", "dropin", {
    container: "checkout",
    form: "checkoutForm",
    defaultFirst: true
});
```

Feature added in braintree JS v2.24.0

Documentation: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration#setup-method-options

Source: https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/76#issuecomment-244162120

Answer (score 0):

i Solved this issue by deleting the payment method immediate after failed or successful transaction.

views.py

```
payment_method_result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
                                        "customer_id": merchant_customer_id,
                                        "amount": am,
                                        "options": {
                                                    "submit_for_settlement": True
                                                  }
                                    })
                # print dir(payment_method_result.transaction)
                # print payment_method_result
                # print payment_method_result.transaction
   try:
      result = braintree.PaymentMethod.delete(payment_method_result.transaction.credit_card['token'])
   except:
      pass
```

as it was one time payment, it did not affected much by deleting the user payment method.
In transaction anyway i can see the details.
Hope this will help some one.